# California housing dataset from sklearn, SSLCertVerificationError

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
housing = fetch_california_housing()
```

This code brings out the error below. How to load it correctly?

```
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:1348, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1347 try:
-> 1348     h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1349               encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1350 except OSError as err: # timeout error
```

Environment: MacBook Air M1, Python 3.10, Jupyter Notebook

Comment: that code works fine for me. seems like something specific to your network. I think these things are downloaded via AWS; do you have any kind of restrictions on your network that might be blocking that?

Comment: @RandomDavis I don't think I have set any kind of options for my network or any antivirus apps. Firewall's inactive. But I'll check my settings again since now I know code itself has got no issue. Thank you!

Comment: Found the solution: add this before the load: `import os, ssl
if (not os.environ.get('PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY', '') and
    getattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context', None)): 
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context`  [link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10201)